# getting all the value of particular key from mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

I have a document in mongoDb in the format as shown below, I want only the value of tag key to print. I have tried several ways but none of them worked

```
{
id = "my_id1"
   tags: 
        {
         'tag1':76, 
         'tag2':77, 
         'tag3':78
        },
   category: "movie",
},
{
   id = "my_id2"
   tags: 
        {
         'tag1':76, 
         'tag2':77, 
         'tag3':78
        },
   category: "tv",
},
{
   id = "my_id3"
   tags: 
        {
         'tag1':76, 
         'tag2':77, 
         'tag3':78
        },
   category: "movie",
}
```

the required output format is as shown bellow

```
76
77
78
76
77
78
76
77
78
```

the code which I am trying is returning me all the other value also.

Comment: You need to use `map_reduce` because your schema design is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your schema is of as follows

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("581707cddb3c8c85a6745d20"),
        "id" : "my_id1",
        "tags" : {
                "tag1" : 76,
                "tag2" : 77,
                "tag3" : 78
        },
        "category" : "movie"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("581707f7db3c8c85a6745d21"),
        "id" : "my_id2",
        "tags" : {
                "tag1" : 76,
                "tag2" : 77,
                "tag3" : 78
        },
        "category" : "tv"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58170a23db3c8c85a6745d22"),
        "id" : "my_id3",
        "tags" : {
                "tag1" : 76,
                "tag2" : 77,
                "tag3" : 78
        },
        "category" : "movie"
}

db.collection.find().count() ---> 3
```

Then the tags value can be retrieved using the below query

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project:{"_id":false,"tags.tag1":1, "tags.tag2":1, "tags.tag3":1}}])
```

This query would yield a result as shown below

```
{ "tags" : { "tag1" : 76, "tag2" : 77, "tag3" : 78 } }
{ "tags" : { "tag1" : 76, "tag2" : 77, "tag3" : 78 } }
{ "tags" : { "tag1" : 76, "tag2" : 77, "tag3" : 78 } }
```

If the schema which I used to get this result is not matching your schema, then you need to modify the query to suit your schema.